# Using MSBuild for Build solution include InstallShield ProjecT

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, installshield

I'm doing a project in C #. In my solution I have an installsheld project that works very well when I compile directly from visual studio, I have a setup that is generated and is ready to be installed.

I would like for various reasons to be able to compile with command-line solution using MSBuild. Everything works but my setup does not generate correctly despite any errors.

Below, the log when I compile the installshield project from visual studio:

[Log InstallShield compile from visual studio](https://justpaste.it/1aqno)

With MSBuild :

[Log InstallShield compile from command line using MSBuild](https://jpst.it/142UR)

We notice that during the step Building File table, from visual studio we have the dependency of component 'RegieCiel.Primary_output', so we are good. Since MSbuild, nothing is added ....

So what happens is that during the installation of the Setup, it lacks the dependencies.

I first thought of a build order but it would work in both cases?

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thank you for your answer and actually I think putting up does not place a solution "static" would solve the problem.

However after a long search I finally found!

In my solution I had a package named "SlowCheetah" to manage several configuration files. By uninstalling it, restart MSbuild, my Setup works perfectly!

Thank you for your help !

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

I avoid project output references like the plague. I suggest having an Application.sln and an Installer.sln.  Have your final projects in application.sln ( EXE, Web Projects )  do a postbuild xcopy or MSBuild publish profile and create a directory that models your deployed application.  From there use one Path Variable in InstallShield  to point to all those files as static links.  Also make sure you turn off all  dependency scanning.  You want to be 100% in control of what does and doesn't go into your project.